# Website shows up in Google search but not on Bing

Tags: search-engine-indexing, search

All of the similar questions are about websites NOT showing up on Google. I did the sitemap, I created the Google console, and it appears the URL does show up in google. If I search site: it shows up. I can also search the words for the url and not the url and it shows up - in Google. Not on Bing, Yahoo, DuckDuckGo, any other search engine.

There are TONS of old references to the title (It's A Kiss From Alexander) but the website itself doesn't show up in any of these search engines. Videos and audio show up in YouTube; old info on the show from 15 years ago shows up, but not the website. I am mystified (And I'm not a coder. I created the website in wordpress using a theme).

Answer (score 1):

For Yahoo and Duckduckgo, you just have to be patient, it will show up eventually.  For Bing, you can submit it to

```
https://www.bing.com/webmasters/about
```

You have to do the usual thing about proving its your site.  Ditto for Yandex, if you are interested.